# Tensor square of duals over a domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, tensor-products

The title is motivated by my needs ($M=N$ in the sequel).

Linked to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086960/tensor-square-of-a-torsion-free-module-r-domain/3088373#3088373) and [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201753/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-can-ax-otimes-a-ay-rightarrow-ax-t?noredirect=1&lq=1) (in the case of products) is the following.

Let $M,N$ $k$-modules ($k$ a commutative ring), then we consider the canonical map
$$
\Phi:M^*\otimes_k N^*\longrightarrow (M\otimes_k N)^* 
$$
defined by 
$$
\Phi(\phi^{(1)}\otimes \phi^{(2)})[u\otimes v]=\phi^{(1)}(u)\phi^{(2)}(v)
$$

I came across the following statement

> **Proposition** Let $M,N$ be modules over $k$, an integral domain, then if $M^*\otimes_k N^*$ is 
>   torsion-free, the canonical map $\Phi$ is into.

**Question 1** Is it known ? (I have a proof - essentially the same as in [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201753/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-can-ax-otimes-a-ay-rightarrow-ax-t?noredirect=1&lq=1) - but no reference).

**Question 2** The example of Jeremy Rickard in the question above showed us that we cannot get rid of the hypothesis [$M^*\otimes_k N^*$ is torsion-free] in the case of domains, under what additional requirements on $k$ (UFD,PID ...) can we get rid of it, then ?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56255/duals-and-tensor-products for related discussion.

Comment: @NeilStrickland I have done, of course, but my need is to explore what happens in non f.g. modules (I am considering spaces like $k\langle\langle X\rangle\rangle$ (with $X$ a non-void alphabet and $k$ a ring). But, thank you (+1).